# URI decoding in Nginx location block

Tags: nginx, decoding, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have reverse proxy nginx setup with the configuration.

```
     upstream cluster {
        least_conn;
        server 192.168.4.137:8001;
        server 192.168.4.137:8002;
    }

    server {
        listen       8000;
        server_name  192.168.4.137;

        charset utf-8;
        log_not_found on;

        access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
        error_log   logs/host.error.log;


        gzip            on;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        gzip_proxied    expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types      text/plain text/xml 
                        text/css 
                        text/comma-separated-values 
                        text/javascript 
                        application/javascript 
                        application/x-javascript 
                        application/atom+xml 
                        application/json 
                        application/x-json;


        location ~ \.(jpg|jpeg)$ {
            internal;
            root D:\\;
        }


        location / {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.4.137:8001;
            proxy_set_header        Host             $host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_read_timeout 1800;
            proxy_connect_timeout 60;
        }
```

The location matcher for jpg /jpeg is **internal redirect** and can contain '%' in file names.

```
location ~ \.(jpg|jpeg)$ {
    internal;
    root D:\\;
 }
```

The '%' is getting decoded and hence 404 is thrown for the wrong names.

I have already tried:

1. using **$request_uri** in proxy pass
2. using **rewrite (.+)%20(.+) "$1%20$2"** in the location block

**UPDATE 1:**
In reponse to the rest call, response is the file path with redirect header:

```
url = "\\Negative\\alcohol%20negative (10).jpeg"
response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = url
```

Error log generate in nginx is :

```
2018/06/16 18:28:45 [error] 15328#2636: *10 CreateFile() "D:\\Negative\alcohol negative (10).jpeg" failed (2: The system cannot find the file specified), client: 192.168.4.137, server: 192.168.4.137, request: "GET /rest/image/imagedata?id=3341869 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.4.137:8001/rest/image/imagedata?id=3341869", host: "192.168.4.137:8000", referrer: "http://192.168.4.137:4200/detail/3341869"
```

None of the above two methods have worked so far.
Please suggest an alternative for the same.

Comment: `%20` is a URL-encoded space. What is the URI of the request, what is the full pathname of the file it should match and what entries in the access and error logs are generated as a result?

Comment: @RichardSmith Please refer to update 1

Comment: To embed a `%` into a URL, you will need to encode it using `%25`, see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for details.

Comment: @RichardSmith This worked. Thanks a ton.